# Find latest timestamp in multiple tables

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo

The javascript runs cyclic task to monitor database, the task (in php) simply queries database for latest timestamp:

```
SELECT
    MAX(po.created)::timestamp last_purchase_order_created,
    MAX(po.modified)::timestamp last_purchase_order_modified,
    MAX(jobs.created)::timestamp last_job_created,
    MAX(jobs.modified)::timestamp last_job_modified,
    MAX(companies.created)::timestamp last_company_created,
    MAX(companies.modified)::timestamp last_company_modified,
    MAX(stock.created)::timestamp last_stock_created,
    MAX(stock.modified)::timestamp last_stock_modified
FROM purchase_orders po, jobs, companies, stock;
```

It started to take long time, because the PHP is not multithreaded, it was blocking other requests too. Is there a way to overcome this? Modified query, different approach in php, bit of both?

This is continuation to problem: [Slow connection to Postgresql using PDO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62759353/slow-connection-to-postgresql-using-pdo)

Comment: It is because your select is performing the full product between tables. To avoid it you have to join tables by some criteria

Answer (score 1):

When you do it this way, you create a Cartesian product across all those tables, and that is highly demanding on your database server.

If you want to do this in one query, then follow this pattern, which will give you one row for each table:

```
select 'purchase_orders' as table_name, max(created) as last_created, max(modified) as last_modified 
  from purchase_orders
union all
select 'jobs', max(created), max(modified) 
  from jobs
union all
select 'companies', max(created), max(modified)
  from companies
union all
select 'stock', max(created), max(modified)
  from stock
```

I would normally pivot this in the host language (PHP, in your case), but if you have to do it inside of the query, then something like this should work:

```
with latest_dates as (
  select 'purchase_orders' as table_name, max(created) as last_created, max(modified) as last_modified 
    from purchase_orders
  union all
  select 'jobs', max(created), max(modified) 
    from jobs
  union all
  select 'companies', max(created), max(modified)
    from companies
  union all
  select 'stock', max(created), max(modified)
    from stock
)
select max(last_created) filter (where table_name = 'purchase_order') as last_purchase_order_created,
       max(last_modified) filter (where table_name = 'purchase_order') as last_purchase_order_modified,
       max(last_created) filter (where table_name = 'job') as last_job_created,
       max(last_modified) filter (where table_name = 'job') as last_job_modified,
       max(last_created) filter (where table_name = 'company') as last_company_created,
       max(last_modified) filter (where table_name = 'company') as last_company_modified,
       max(last_created) filter (where table_name = 'stock') as last_stock_created,
       max(last_modified) filter (where table_name = 'stock') as last_stock_modified
  from latest_dates;
```

Comment: Alright, I'll give it a go. I don't see why not do this in php, except I thought it would be quicker at the pgsql side.

Comment: @adiDX  I would normally pivot inside of PHP since you can loop through the rows and create your array names dynamically using `table_name`.

Comment: It's interesting, how much faster Mike's query runs in comparison to mine - 5s down to ~100ms! There is still so much I have to learn about how the PostgreSQL mechanics work.

Answer (score 1):

A `UNION` query like Mike recommended would be better, but if you want that query fast, you'd need an index on *every* column that you take a `max` of.

This seems like a strange query to run often. Is thus a substitute for what would better be done with a sequence?

If you really need those maxima often, you could maintain a special table that contains only those maxima and is updated whenever you insert or update a row. That would save you many expensive indexes.

Comment: Thank you both. The `UNION` is quick, temp fix. I'll look into creating separate table for this purpose later. 

Comment: Yea I was thinking something similar, like a event-log table. But since you need just the latest for each table its much better to store and update only these.